# How facebook app implements draggable floating Button

Tags: android, button, draggable, floating

I´m trying to get some information about how I could implement such a Button like Facebook does in the new version of the app. Actually I am not sure if this button comes from Facebook or from Facebook messenge app but it was the easiest way to have an example of what I would like to achieve.

They add a draggable floating Button anywhere you are when getting a new message notification, anybody has and idea about how they achieved that?

Thanks in advance.

Edited:

Toucher: other app which uses what I´d like to achieve. Just below can find a link from Google Play

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.touchhelperex&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5nYXUuZ28udG91Y2hoZWxwZXJleCJd

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android

Comment: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see if this help

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531

this library has drag view outside the app